# iOS 6 issue during setting text on a label

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I've a problem with some label. I made a public method that takes information from a table view and shows this info in 3 label, a text view and it load a pic from the web. I setup all the variable in the table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, but I'm having some issue to display that info. I made so:
in the table view controller I called the other method so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.detailCharacterViewController = [[DetailCharacterViewController alloc] init];
    [self.detailCharacterViewController setupDetailViewControllerWithName:[self.arrayCharacters[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] andSurname:[self.arrayCharacters[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"surname"] andKind:[self.arrayCharacters[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"kind"] andDescription:[self.arrayCharacters[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"] andImage:[self.arrayCharacters[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"URLpic"]];
}
```

and I implemented the method so:

```
    - (void)setupDetailViewControllerWithName:(NSString*)name andSurname:(NSString *)surname andKind:(NSString*) kind andDescription:(NSString*)description andImage:(NSString*)url {
    NSLog(@"name = %@", name);
    self.labelName.text = name;
    self.labelSurname.text = surname;
    self.labelKind.text = kind;
    self.textDescription.text = description;

    NSURL *urlPic = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSData *dataPic = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlPic];
    [self.imagePic setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dataPic]];
}
```

If I look to the log i see the right things, but if I look to the GUI on iPhone or iPhone simulator it will remain blank. What's wrong with this code?
Thank you for the suggestion.

@Alex Blundell

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface DetailCharacterViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelSurname;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelKind;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imagePic;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textDescription;

- (void)setupDetailViewControllerWithName:(NSString*)name andSurname:(NSString *)surname andKind:(NSString*) kind andDescription:(NSString*)description andImage:(NSString*)url;

@end
```

Comment: Check for outlets hooked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `DetailCharacterViewController`'s view is not loaded yet when you call `setupDetailViewControllerWithName:...`, so none of the outlets are connected (yet). Instantiating a view controller via alloc-init does *not* load its view automatically.

You could force loading the view by calling `[self view]` at the beginning of your setup method. This works because accessing the `view` property will automatically load the view if it wasn't loaded before.

Alternatively, you could make the `name`, `surname`, etc. `NSString` properties of the view controller and set the corresponding labels in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I tried the first solution you suggest to me, but nothing... Still the same... With the second solution, the issue will be the same... No text in the variable NSString *name. I initialized it in the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath so: 

self.detailCharacterViewController.name = [self.arrayCharacters[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

Comment: I created a property for detailCharacterViewController

Comment: How are you actually showing the `detailCharacterViewController`? In the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method you're just setting it up, but how/where are you presenting it on screen?

Comment: If I press on the row I'm interesting it will send me to the DetailCharacterViewController by a segue. So I show the view controller after tap on a row of the table view

Comment: Then I bet that the detail view controller you're showing is not the same as the one you're setting up. As you're using a storyboard segue, you should implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` and set up the destination view controller of the `UIStoryboardSegue` there. The storyboard instantiates a view controller for you, the one you're instantiating manually is never actually used (try logging `self` in your setup method and `self.detailCharacterViewController` in your table view method – they won't be the same).

Comment: I understand now, I will try to fix the problem. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Interface Builder/Storyboards to design your interface? Have you made sure to connect the IBOutlets for each UITextField/View?

You should identify the objects in the header file on your view controller class, and ensure they're prefixed by IBOutlet for them to appear in Interface Builders connections pane. E.g.

```
IBOutlet UITextField labelName;
[...]
```

Then you need to go to IB and go to the connections pane for the view controller to connect each text field/view.

Comment: I connected all label, text view and image view... (if you look at my post you can see my .h file).

Comment: the outlets being in your `.h` file doesn't necessarily mean it's hooked up correctly. Right-click one of the labels in `Interface Builder` and see if the connection is as you expect.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure because I haven't worked with the attributes such as 'weak' etc, but I've always had to put my IBOutlets in the Interface section inside {} brackets. Does it work if you move them out of the @property declarations?

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me as well.

It has to do with the fact that iOS actually hooks up your outlets *really really* late.

If you put a breakpoint in your `setupDetailViewControllerWithName:` and check your IBOutlet variables, they will be nil. That's why you are seeing a blank view. (The good old nil erroring)

The work-around I will do is to declare properties in the `DetailCharacterViewController` class. (Such as `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString* name`).

And in the place where you are calling `setupDetailViewControllerWithName:`, set those properties instead such as:

`self.detailCharacterViewController.name = name;`

Finally in your `DetailCharacterViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:`, you set the values of the labels using the saved properties. (The outlets are for sure hooked up then).

(By the way, this problem exists for `prepareForSegue:` as well. The destination view controller's outlets are all still nil in `prepareForSegue:`. So you cannot set them directly there yet)